# Using AVR on Arduino, trying to get pin7 to flash on and off

Tags: arduino, avr

I'm trying to get this to toggle pin 7 on and off but I'm having some issues. What's the correct way to do this?  I'm fairly certain my issue is in the toggleLED function between the two "state" lines.

```
   #include <avr/io.h>

int state = 1;
char ticks = 0;

void toggleLED(void);

int main(void) {
    DDRB = (1 << PD7);        // set pin 7 to output
    TIMSK0 = 0;             // no interrupts
    TCCR0B = 5;             // divide clock by 1024
    PORTB = (1<<PD7);

    while(1) {
        while((TIFR0 & 0x01) == 0) {}    // loop until flag is set

        TIFR0 = 1;              // clear the flag
        ticks++;
        if(ticks == 1) {
            ticks = 0;
            toggleLED();
        }
    }
} 

 void toggleLED(void) {
     if(state == 1) {
        PORTB = 1;
        state = 0;
     } else {
        PORTB = 0;
        state = 1;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `main` function sets PB7. Your `toggleLED` function toggles PB0. Pin 7 is probably something else, we would need to know which hardware this running on to tell what pin 7 is.

Comment: In theory, this should make it work, no?        int main(void) {
        DDRB &= ~(1 << PD7);        // set pin 7 to output
          PORTD |=(1<<7);}

Comment: guess not, needs an on off loop not constant voltage.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```C++
#include <avr/io.h>

ISR (TIMER0_COMPA_vect)
  {
  PIND = (1 << PIND7);        // toggle D7
  }  

int main(void) 
  {
    DDRD   = (1 << PORTD7);        // set pin D7 to output
    TCCR0A = 0;                
    TCCR0B = (1 << CS00) | (1 << CS02);  // prescaler of 1024
    TIMSK0 = (1 << OCIE0A);    // Timer/Counter0 Output Compare Match A Interrupt Enable
    OCR0A  = 249;              // count up to 250
    sei ();                    // want interrupts now
    while (true) ;             // all done!
  }
```

That toggles pin 7 at a rate of 62.5 Hz. (ie. the frequency is 31.25 Hz, which is visible).

Theory:

```C++
 16e6 / 1024 / 250 = 62.5 Hz
```

---

Or let the hardware do it for you:

```C++
#include <avr/io.h>

int main(void) 
  {
    DDRD   = (1 << PORTD6);        // set pin 6 to output
    TCCR0A = (1 << COM0A0);        // toggle OC0A on compare match               
    TCCR0B = (1 << CS00) | (1 << CS02);  // prescaler of 1024
    OCR0A  = 249;                 // count up to 250
  }
```

Note that this is now on pin D6 (pin 12 on the chip) because it is using a hardware timer output.